# How to remove file type association with opening program?

Tags: windows-7, file-types

I wanted to open it (.srt file) with notepad, typed it in the first textbox I found and now I can't remove the word "notepad" from the Type collumn when I use SMPlayer as default program to open .srt files. It bugts my OCD, help me please! I just want it to say "SRT File" as it did by default

[image]

Comment: Have tried resetting the default file assoications?

Comment: AT Rambound you wrote "Have tried resetting the default file assoications? " <---  as if there's a reset button that resets all file associations. As if it's some option that's well known or even exists. Why don't you tell him where this so-called option is.  And when I look I see http://i.imgur.com/pFedANm.png  notepad not listed and the option isn't called reset there either. and it doesn't affect all either. So not only are you not telling him where the option is, you are describing the option as if  it's some well known description of an option, but it doesn't seem to be.

Comment: AT Ramhound so you should tell him what option you mean.

Comment: I've tried doing "assoc .srt" in CMD prompt, but it says "File association not found for extension .srt" So I can't reset anything there.

Comment: Won't that just make notepad default instead of SMPlayer?

Answer (score 1):

Had to go to regedit and search for "srt" in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, finding "srt_auto_file". I could modify the setting to blank and then restart Explorer. Solved the problem.